# Use dummy variables to create a ranked mutually exclusive variable. R

Tags: r, rank, dummy-variable, mutual-exclusion

I have a series of multiple response (dummy) variables describing causes for a canceled visits. A visit can have multiple reasons for the cancelation. My goal is to create a single mutually exclusive variable using the dummy variables in a hierarchical way. For example, in my sample data below the rank of my variables is as follow: Medical, NoID and Refuse. Ex. if a visit was cancelled due to medical and  lack of ID reasons, I would like to recode my final variable as "medical" since is more important base on my rank. Likewise VisitID 3 was cancelled due to no ID and refuse visit, in this case I would like to recode this cancellation as NoID since NoID is more important than Refuse.
Thank you for any help!

```
  VisitID  NoID Refuse Medical WhatINeed
1       1  TRUE  FALSE    TRUE   Medical
2       2 FALSE  FALSE   FALSE      <NA>
3       3  TRUE   TRUE   FALSE      NoID
```

```
structure(list(VisitID = c(1, 2, 3), NoID = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE
), Refuse = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), Medical = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE
), WhatINeed = c("Medical", NA, "NoID")), row.names = c(NA, 3L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can loop over the rows with `apply` after selecting the columns in the order of importance, get the `names` from the logical vector and extract the first name that corresponds to TRUE value

```
df1$WhatINeed <- apply(df1[c("Medical", "NoID", "Refuse")], 1, 
    FUN = function(x) names(x)[x][1])
```

-outupt

```
> df1
  VisitID  NoID Refuse Medical WhatINeed
1       1  TRUE  FALSE    TRUE   Medical
2       2 FALSE  FALSE   FALSE      <NA>
3       3  TRUE   TRUE   FALSE      NoID
```